# Sums of squared distances between points on an $n$-sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have discovered the following results about the sums of squared distances between points on an $n$-sphere (and proved them).  To the best of my knowledge (and my advisor's knowledge), these results are new.  However, since this is classical geometry and the proofs are not hard, I wanted to ask if anyone knows of their existence in the literature.

I have searched the literature, and I do find authors considering similar questions (e.g., what distribution of points on an $n$-sphere maximizes the sum of distances between the points) but I do not see anyone considering the sum of *squared* distances.

I want to emphasize that I am *not* asking for proofs of these results.  I have already proven them myself.

First, a bit of terminology:

- An *$n$-sphere* is the set of all points equidistance from a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- A set of points $\mathcal{V}$ is *centrally symmetric* if it is closed under the antipodal map, i.e., for every $P \in \mathcal{V}$, the point $-P$ is in $\mathcal{V}$.
- A set of points $\mathcal{V}$ is *transitive* if for each $P, Q \in \mathcal{V}$, there exists a symmetry of $\mathcal{V}$ such that $P$ is mapped to $Q$.

**Result 1**. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a set of $V$ points on a unit $n$-sphere, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the multiset of the lengths of all the chords between them.
Then: $$\sum_{c \, \in \, \mathcal{C}}c^2= V^{2}(1-d^2)$$
where $d$ is the distance between the centroid of $\mathcal{V}$ and the center of the unit $n$-sphere.

This leads to a nice corollary:  The centroid of $\mathcal{V}$ coincides with the center of the $n$-sphere *if and only if* $\sum_{c \, \in \, \mathcal{C}}c^2= V^{2}$.

**Result 2**. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a transitive, centrally symmetric set of $V$ points on a unit $n$-sphere, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of distinct lengths of all the chords between them.
Then: $$\sum_{l \, \in \, \mathcal{L}}l^2 = 2k+2$$
where $k$ is the cardinality of $\mathcal{L}$.

Question:  Has anyone seen these results in the literature?  If so, where?  (I suppose reference to any similar results would be helpful as well...)

Note:  My research was motivated by the following two facts found in the literature.  My results subsume these (if one thinks of the vertices of a regular polygon as a point configuration).

1. For a regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle, $\sum_{c \, \in \, \mathcal{C}}c^2= V^{2}$.
2. For a regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle, $\sum_{l \, \in \, \mathcal{L}}l^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Fact 1 is in an unpublished paper by S. Mustonen at
https://www.survo.fi/papers/Roots2013.pdf.  Fact 2 is in a popular math book by J. Kappraff: "Beyond Measure: A
Guided Tour through Nature, Myth, and Number." (World Scientific
Publishing, River Edge, NJ, 2002). A related question was stated as
a 1923 MAA Monthly problem (Morley, F. V., Harding, A. M.: 2925. Am.
Math. Mon. 30(1), 44 (1923)).

Comment: I don't understand the definition of *transitive* (but that's OK, since you never use it).

Comment: @GerryMyerson. It's easier to understand if you think about the convex hull of the point set--i.e., a convex polytope.  The polytope has symmetries, and it is (vertex) transitive if any vertex of the polytope can be mapped to any other vertex via a symmetry of the polytope...  Does that help?

Comment: Result 2 seems surprising.  My combinatorial intuition would be that counting *distinct* chord lengths should be much messier than that.  Does anyone have any intuition as to why this *should have* come out as nice as it did?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for pointing out that I hadn't used "transitive."  It was supposed to be a hypothesis for Result 2.  I have fixed this in my question, and also reworded the definition of "transitive" to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: Update: Many thanks to everyone for their thoughts on this topic! I have now finished a paper stating and proving these two results as well as an application to normalized frames (thanks to Dustin G. Mixon for alerting me to a connection). The paper is on the arXiv: arxiv.org/abs/2001.02745.

Answer (score 11):

There are two basic formulae for the moment of inertia, which I formulate for the system of unit masses: given $V$ points $p_1,\dots,p_V\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define by $J(q)=\sum |q-p_i|^2$ the moment of intertia of a point $q$. Then

1) (Lagrange formula) $J(q)=J(z)+V|q-z|^2$, where $z$ is the centroid of our $V$ points.

2) (Jacobi formula) $J(z)=V^{-1}\sum_{i<j} |p_i-p_j|^2$.

These formulae are known under different names, I follow the book of Balk and Boltyanskiy "Geometry of masses".

Comment: To clarify:  $n$ is the dimension of the space and $V$ is the number of points, right?  Since you say "our $n$ points" in the first formula, I'm wondering which of the $n$'s in the formula should be $V$'s.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected

Comment: @FedorPetrov I'm familiar with moment of inertia around an axis, but not moment of inertia at a point.  Could you explain what you mean by this?  (I tried to look at "Geometry of masses," but my Russian is not good.)

Comment: In general it is $\sum_i m_i |q-p_i|^2 $, where $m_i$ are masses in $p_i$. For axis the same, but you take the squares of distances to the axis, not to the point.

Answer (score 6):

The sum of squares of chords has proven to be particularly useful in studying arrangements of lines for redundant linear encodings of data.

Suppose $n=\binom{d+1}{2}$. In this case, we may identify $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the vector space of real symmetric $d\times d$ matrices, and $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{P}^{d-1}$ with the subset of matrices that represent orthogonal projections of rank 1:

$$
\mathbb{R}\mathbf{P}^{d-1}
\cong\{xx^\top:x\in S^{d-1}\}.
$$

Notice that these matrices have unit Frobenius norm, and so they reside in the unit sphere in this space of matrices. The square of the chord length between $xx^\top$ and $yy^\top$ is given by

$$
\|xx^\top-yy^\top\|_F^2
=2-2(x^\top y)^2.
$$

As such, the sum of the squared chord lengths between pairs in $\mathcal{V}=\{x_ix_i^\top\}_{i=1}^V$ is given by

$$
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq V}\|x_ix_i^\top-x_jx_j^\top\|_F^2
=V^2-\sum_{i=1}^V\sum_{j=1}^V(x_i^\top x_j)^2.
$$

The double sum on the right-hand side is the ***frame potential*** of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^V$, studied extensively by Benedetto and Fickus in "[Finite Normalized Tight Frames](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021323312367)." (It's a beautiful paper!)

Answer (score 5):

I read your paper (Sums of squared distances between points on a Unit sphere 2020 arXiv), but I must inform you that your theorem 2.1 was already established by Tom M. Apostol in a paper in Math Monthly 2003 (Sums of squares of distances in m-space) in a more general way (weighted).

Comment: For sure Jessie Copher has an email address (that you can find in his articles, or with an internet search) where you can send him your remarks.

Comment: For clarification, theorem 2.1 in the paper is Result 1 as written in the question.  That is, this is in fact an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @user160316 Thank you very much for pointing this out to me.  It's sad news (for me), but you have saved me a good deal of time!